# iOS - SQLite insertion not inserting data

Tags: ios, sqlite

```
- (id)init {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"idataBase.sqlite3"];
    NSLog(@"Doc path: %@",databasePath);
    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if (!databaseAlreadyExists){
        NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"idataBase" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
        NSLog(@"Main bundle path: %@",databasePathFromApp);
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    }
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &_database) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Database opened");
    }dd
    return self;
}

-(void) setData:(NSDictionary *)data{
    NSLog(@"In Data %@",data);
    NSString *hostAddress = [data objectForKey:@"hostAddress"];
    NSString *userName = [data objectForKey:@"userName"];
    NSString *passKey = [data objectForKey:@"passKey"];
    NSString *listName = [data objectForKey:@"listName"];
    NSString *q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO user_info (host_name,user_name,password,text_name) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",hostAddress,userName,passKey,listName];
    NSLog(@"%@",q);
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement = NULL;
    const char *insertQuery = [q UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, insertQuery, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"Data Inserted");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_database);
```

}

I am using the above code for inserting data. Database connection is opened in init method. But I cannot insert data in database. sqlite3_step(statement) never returns SQLITE_OK.

Comment: First major problem - you are building your query using `stringWithFormat`. Don't do it that way. Make proper use of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` to bind values into your query. And use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log the error whenever something fails. And check the result of the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. I mentioned most of this in your last question about deleting data. You need to do proper error checking.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. It sohows some error "library routine called out of sequence"

Comment: You didn't fix the other issue I pointed out in your other question. You still have unbalanced calls to `sqlite3_open` and `sqlite3_close`. Does this class have other methods that work on the database? Be sure all method properly call `prepare`, `step`, `finalize`. And put the `close` in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: And consider using FMDB instead of raw sqlite.

Comment: rmaddy is right that FMDB is worth considering, as it greatly simplifies the process for you. Notably, using `?` placeholders in your SQL (which is very important to do) requires a ton of `sqlite3_bind_xxx` calls if using the C interface, but FMDB takes the pain out of the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> sqlite3_step(statement) never returns SQLITE_OK.

Correct, if successful, it returns `SQLITE_DONE` (when doing an insert/update/delete query). See [sqlite3_step documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

And if you don't get `SQLITE_DONE`, then you should check `sqlite3_errmsg` to determine why. If it's reporting "library routine called out of sequence" error, that probably means that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` failed, its effectively saying that it's seeing `sqlite3_step` without a successful `sqlite3_prepare_v2` call.

So, you should also check the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2` (as that is, more frequently, the source of the problem) and make sure that is `SQLITE_OK`, and if not, look at `sqlite3_errmsg` immediately, before calling `sqlite3_step`. If you have an error from `sqlite3_prepare_v2` and ignore the error and just call `sqlite3_step`, you'll lose the meaningful error message that you could have checked before calling `sqlite3_step`, replacing the meaningful error message with a "library routine called out of sequence" error.

---

This is pure conjecture, but given your other questions about issues in copying a database, I might wager that at some time in your testing, you ran a rendition of your code that failed to copy the database, but still proceeded to call `sqlite3_open`. And `sqlite3_open` will create a blank database if it doesn't find one. Thus, I wouldn't be surprised if the database was blank and therefore the error message from `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is going to report that the table is not found. If my conjecture is correct (that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` is failing and calling `sqlite3_errmsg` is reporting that the table is not found), I'd suggest removing the app from your simulator/device (to remove any blank databases sitting in `Documents` folder) and try running the app again. I'd also make sure that your code does not attempt to open the database if the copy from the bundle failed (or else you'll risk creating a blank database again). I might also suggest replacing your `sqlite3_open` code with:

```
if (sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath UTF8String], &_database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    NSLog(@"Database opened");
```

This is just like `sqlite3_open`, but this will not create a blank database if it doesn't find one.

---

So, the routine, checking all the SQLite return codes and using `?` placeholders in the SQL might look like:

```
- (void)insertUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSString *hostAddress = dictionary[@"hostAddress"];
    NSString *userName    = dictionary[@"userName"];
    NSString *passKey     = dictionary[@"passKey"];
    NSString *listName    = dictionary[@"listName"];

    const char *sql = "INSERT INTO user_info (host_name,user_name,password,text_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        return;
    }

    if (![self bindString:hostAddress column:1 statement:statement])
        return;

    if (![self bindString:userName column:2 statement:statement])
        return;

    if (![self bindString:passKey column:3 statement:statement])
        return;

    if (![self bindString:listName column:4 statement:statement])
        return;

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Data Inserted");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Where the method to bind a string value to a column might look like:

```
- (BOOL)bindString:(NSString *)value column:(NSInteger)column statement:(sqlite3_stmt *)statement
{
    if (value) {
        if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, column, [value UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"bind column %d to %@ failed: %s", column, value, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        if (sqlite3_bind_null(statement, column) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"bind column %d to null failed: %s", column, sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to knock you this way. But I am stuck with a problem for a long time. I don't know what I am missing here. I am really sorry sir. If you get time please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852420/ui-stucks-in-ios-app-possible-reason-is-fmdb-query

That will be a great help. I don't know anyone except you who can help.